# User Control in a Repeater with Async

Tags: .net, webforms, user-controls, async-await

I'm trying to bind a user control in a ASP Repeater in a async .Net Web Form Page but binding the repeater item to a public property of a user control is failing.

If I hard code (rather than bind) to a proprty it is passed through correctly
If I output the repeater data item without passing to the user control the value is outputted
If I create a new list and bind to the repeater i.e. not using await to get the data from the API call like in the code, then the bound property (Eval("id")) is passed through ok to the user control.

Page Code

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(TaskAsync));
}

private async Task TaskAsync()
{
    List<API.Models.Question> questions = await Data.Question.GetQuestions();

    QuestionRepeater.DataSource = questions;
    QuestionRepeater.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataSource = questions;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Page Front End

```
 <asp:repeater ID="QuestionRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Id") %><%-- WORKS--%>
        <uc1:QuestionContainer ID="QuestionContainer1" runat="server" QuestionText='<%# Eval("Id") %>' x="this works!" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Control Code

```
[Bindable(true)]
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
[Bindable(true)]
public string x { get; set; }
```

I'm sure this is down to the async element of retreiving the data but if I debug I can see the list of questions is pulled back with data and the repeater loops the correct number of times its just not pasing the value through to the user control

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: I doubt very much this is related to async. What have you done to debug this?

Comment: So I have created a new list of questions in the code behind, bound that to the repeater and the Eval("id") passes through to the control fine.
I've debugged and inspected the list of questions when retrieved via async/API and can see the contents fine, if I output them in the repeater it all works fine (see comment WORKS in code) but if I bind it to a user control property as in the question then QuestionText is null. If however I hard code a string in there instead of binding then that comes out fine (see property x in code above).
Why do you not think this is down to the async/await

Comment: I don't think it's down to async/await. Quite the contrary. On PreRenderComplete does the repeater have the expected data?

Comment: Yes the repeater has the correct data, I have 2 items in the list and it outputs two instances of the ItemTemplate content, but it is not passing through the value into the QuestionText='<%# Eval("Id") %>' property of the user control

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: Yes as mentioned, I have debugged it, the repeater has the right data, the usercontrol shows null unless I get the list of questions not using async/await and then everything works fine as expected when binding a user control in a repeater.